# How to extract a particular value from a string in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have a string which stores the output of a webservices response in JSON form. in this string I want to get the `INI` value, it will be either true or false. I just want to get the `INI` value how to extract the value from the string below in c#

```
string a= {"active":"true","firstName":"stac","lastName":"Over","INI":"true","userID":"0"}
```

Comment: The code you have posted isn't valid.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem possible. Either I'm having a moment, or you're missing a class declaration or more quotes.

Comment: I think it just misses the outer quotes...

Answer (score 7):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use the built-in [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx):

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)serializer.DeserializeObject(a);
string ini = (string)dictionary["INI"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The response that you get is a JSONObject. One approach is to take your response and use a JSON library to parse out the values. Like Thomas' answer above, you'll be able to treat it like a dictionary and given a key, "INI", get the value from your response object.

Cheers.